# Help understanding Diamagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism

I need some help understanding Wikipedia description of diamagnetism
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism

In the first sentence of the first paragraph, when said

"*...induced magnetic field in the direction opposite the externally applied magnetic field, and are repelled by the magnetic field."*

By direction opposite they are saying the direction of the magnetic field, or vector B in this  [depiction of the right hand rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dn9Q.jpg)?
And, am i right in thinking that the directions of the fields being in opposition is why they repel each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes. The directions of the magnetic field lines refer to the direction of $\vec{B}$. Since the external and induced magnetic field vectors face in opposite directions to each other, there is a repulsive force.